# ASP .NET Excel file getting corrupted when downloaded office 365 Pro Plus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, http, office365

ASP.net webform application first

- step 1) we generate an excel based on the templates.
- Step 2) This excel is been edited & uploaded back.
- Step 3) The user can then download the uploaded file.

The problem is when the user is downloading an Uploaded file.
If we open the generated file in Office 365 pro plus excel, in after Step 1 and saved it. when we get a corrupted excel .xlsx file on step 3.

This issue is only happening with this Office 365 version. If I do the edit in any other version it works fine. Please help if you guys know the answers

```
response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Concat("attachment; filename=", fileName));
response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
response.ContentType = contentType;
stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

I'm doing the above to get the excel file downloaded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read through the guidelines on how to ask a good question to increase your chances of getting high quality responses. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What code do you use for editing the document? It seems the problem is in editing the document.